# macOS shell script check. A better way to execute the if statement and check for a condition

Tags: terminal, command-line, big-sur, script

I need to write a very simple shell script that will check if the system is configured to enforce multi-factor authentication.

To verify that the system is configured to enforce multi-factor authentication, run the following commands:

```
/usr/sbin/system_profiler SPConfigurationProfileDataType | /usr/bin/grep enforceSmartCard
```

If the results do not show "**enforceSmartCard=1**", this is a finding.

I created this very simple script, but I am pretty sure there is a more effective, elegant and efficient way to achieve the same result.

Basically if it was you, what kind of modifications would you apply to the script below to achieve the same results?

Thank you so much in advance for your help.

```
#!/bin/zsh

myVAR=`/usr/sbin/system_profiler SPConfigurationProfileDataType | /usr/bin/grep enforceSmartCard`

if [ $myVAR = "enforceSmartCard=1" ]
then
    echo "The system is configured to enforce multi-factor authentication"
else
    echo "The system is not configured to enforce multi-factor authentication"
fi
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean with simpler, seems to be rather simple already?

Comment: You could get rid of the variable by running the commands within the if, but readability would suffer.

Comment: If I were at you, I would probably just change the shebang.

Comment: @Rakib Fiha, RE: "If I were at you, I would probably just change the shebang." --  Why?  FYI In a default clean install of **macOS Big Sur** the default `shell` is `zsh`.

Comment: OP asked specifically what I would do. I just happen to run latest bash as my default shell for personal reasons (like posix compatibility and so on) and I do a lot of scripting in bash for my work to have Linux compatibility. So my shebang in most cases is #!/usr/bin/env bash. But here, clearly OP doesn’t need to bother about those issues.

Comment: Good point, don‘t use `zsh` if `sh` is enough (which it is for a script like this).

Answer (score 3):

This might be a little more elegant, not necessarily *simpler*: I'm wrapping the parts of the pipeline in their own functions

```bsh
profile () { /usr/sbin/system_profiler SPConfigurationProfileDataType; }
enforces2fa () { /usr/bin/grep -F -q 'enforceSmartCard=1'; }

if profile | enforces2fa; then
    echo "The system is configured to enforce multi-factor authentication"
else
    echo "The system is not configured to enforce multi-factor authentication"
fi
```

Some notes

- prefer `$(...)` over `` `...` `` for command substitution: it's easier to read.
- `if` takes a *command* and branches based on the command's *exit status*. At a bash prompt, enter `help if` for more details.

  - `[` is a bash builtin command, not just syntax.
- if "enforceSmartCard=1" is the only text on the line, add `-x` to the grep options.

Additionally, you can modify the PATH in your script to streamline the functions

```bsh
PATH=$(getconf PATH)      # /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

profile () { system_profiler SPConfigurationProfileDataType; }
enforces2fa () { grep -F -q 'enforceSmartCard=1'; }
```

This is only in effect for the duration of the running script, and will not affect your interactive shell.

Comment: `getconf PATH` might be dangerous if other parts of the script rely on commands stored in `/usr/local/bin` or similar. In general I wouldn't specify paths for commands which are in the standard paths. If PATH doesn't include them other stuff may not work either.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be inclined to read the value of the **`enforceSmartCard`** key directly from the *`com.apple.security.smartcard.plist`* file located in the *`/Library/Preferences`* folder.

This can be done using the `defaults` command-line tool, which will be significantly faster than the `system_profiler`, and you won't need to `grep` its output:

```
defaults read /Library/Preferences/com.apple.security.smartcard enforceSmartCard
```

Here are the possible outputs for the `system_profiler | grep` and `defaults` commands, together with their meaning:

| `system_profiler | grep` | `defaults` |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `enforceSmartCard=0` | 0 | The `enforceSmartCard` key is set, and its value is `false` |
| `enforceSmartCard=1` | 1 | The `enforceSmartCard` key is set, and its value is `true` |
| *non-zero exit status* | *Error message* and *non-zero exit status* | The `enforceSmartCard` key is *not* set, **or** (`defaults` only) the property list does not exist |

The default value for `enforceSmartCard` is `false`, therefore a non-zero exit status is essentially equivalent in meaning—for our purposes—to `enforceSmartCard=0`.  In the case of the `defaults` command, an error message is also printed that looks something like this:

```
The domain/default pair of (/Library/Preferences/com.apple.security.smartcard, enforceSmartCard) does not exist
```

so, provided there isn't a typographical error when you issue the command, then either the file */Library/Preferences/com.apple.security.smartcard.plist* does not exist, or it does and the `enforceSmartCard` key is not set.  Either way, the error message is of little value, so this can be suppressed by redirecting *`stderr`* into the void:

```
defaults read /Library/Preferences/com.apple.security.smartcard enforceSmartCard 2>/dev/null
```

Thus, the predicate we discriminate upon will be whether or not this command outputs `"1"` (without quotes): if it does, then a user must authenticate using their smart card  (in addition to whatever other form of authentication would be required); any other result (either an output of `"0"`, or a non-zero exit status with no output) infers that a user may authenticate without using a smart card.

Here's the final script that should be equivalent to yours:

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

plist=/Library/Preferences/com.apple.security.smartcard

(( $( defaults read "$plist" \
enforceSmartCard 2>/dev/null )
)) && i=1 _not= || 
      i=2 _not=not

printf '%s ' The system is ${_not} configured to \
             enforce multi-factor authentication \
             >/dev/fd/$i
```

Comment: JSYK The _output_ is atypical in that while the _prompt_ returns to a normal position, nonetheless, the _message_ has a trailing _space_ and whatever the _prompt character_ is after it, highlighted, and doesn't look at all normal to _standard output_.  Changing `printf '%s '` to `echo` will eliminate the strange _output_.

Comment: @user3439894- Wouldn't `printf '%s \n'` fix the issue?

Comment: OK, you need to quote the desired output. ...my bad....

Comment: Quoting it as it's currently shown the _output_ would be on two lines and why I originally said... Changing `printf '%s '` to `echo` will eliminate the strange _output_.

Comment: CJK, I didn't realize that was fd0 that comment back and I deleted the picture link, so have a look at: https://i.imgur.com/r7HKU7w.png

Comment: I'd suggest using `printf 'The system is%s configured to enforce multi-factor authentication\n' "$_not"` which means you need `_not=" not"` in the error case.

Comment: @user3439894 Thanks for the picture.  That looks ideal to me, but it appears that on your system, the highlighted prompt character is inserted by the terminal, probably to indicate that the proceeding newline character is not part of the output.  Had the terminal not edited the output, there would simply be a space separating the end of _”authentication”_ and the start of the new the prompt (on the same line), which is how it appears on my system. As a rule, I use `echo` only for debugging, and `printf` for operational output. _Cont’d…_

Comment: _…Cont’d_ The nature of the task feels more like an intermediate step in a larger script, so output might not be warranted and simply disposing of everything from `&&` onwards would reduce the solution to a one-liner, for which the exit status of `(( … ))` has the greatest utility.  Should the OP desire a printed output, I’d suggest appending one more line of code that can simply be `printf \\n`, purely so that the command-line prompt starts on its own line if their terminal doesn’t already handle this for them.